# How can I avoid code duplication when creating similar elements in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I made code for small text editor with swing. I have many similar components that do similar actions. Similar code is duplicated many times. For instance, the code like following is repeated many times for different font sizes:

```
pkt8 = new JMenuItem("8 pts");
pkt8.addActionListener(this);
fontsize.add(pkt8);
...
if (e.getSource() == pkt8) {
  textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 8))
...
```

**How can I change my code to avoid such duplication?**

Here is the full code:

```
package zad6;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MenuKeyEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MenuKeyListener;
import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;

public class DrawSwing {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Ramka();
        }
    });
}
}

class Ramka implements ActionListener {

// kolory 1-blue,2-yellow,3-orange,4-red,5-white,6-black,7-green
JMenuItem c1;
JMenuItem c2;
JMenuItem c3;
JMenuItem c4;
JMenuItem c5;
JMenuItem c6;
JMenuItem c7;
JMenuItem c1f;
JMenuItem c2f;
JMenuItem c3f;
JMenuItem c4f;
JMenuItem c5f;
JMenuItem c6f;
JMenuItem c7f;
JMenuItem pkt8;
JMenuItem pkt10;
JMenuItem pkt12;
JMenuItem pkt14;
JMenuItem pkt16;
JMenuItem pkt18;
JMenuItem pkt20;
JMenuItem pkt22;
JMenuItem pkt24;
JTextArea textArea;
JMenuItem szkola;
JMenuItem praca;
JMenuItem dom;
BufferedReader br;
String line;
FileDialog fd;
static String path;

public Ramka() {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();

    jf.setTitle("Prosty edytor - bez tytulu");
    jf.pack();
    jf.setSize(500, 500);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    jf.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    textArea.setEditable(true);
    jf.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    jf.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Główne menu
    // File menu
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    // Open
    JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open", new ImageIcon("src/src/if_simpline_4_2305586.png"));
    open.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL + KeyEvent.VK_O);
    open.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    fileMenu.add(open);
    open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            fd = new FileDialog(jf, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
            textArea.setText("");
            fd.setVisible(true);
            String katalog = fd.getDirectory();
            String plik = fd.getFile();
            System.out.println(fd.getFile());
            path = katalog + plik;
            jf.setTitle("Prosty edytor - " + path);
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                line = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (line != null) {
                textArea.append(line + "\n");
                try {
                    line = br.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    fileMenu.addSeparator();
    // Save
    JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save", new ImageIcon("src/src/if_simpline_53_2305609.png"));
    save.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    fileMenu.add(save);
    save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            File f2 = new File(path);
            jf.setTitle("Prosty edytor - " + path);
            try {
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f2));
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(textArea.getText()));
                String line;

                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                    out.write(line);
                out.newLine();
                out.close();

            } catch (AccessDeniedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    fileMenu.addSeparator();
    // Saveas
    JMenuItem saveas = new JMenuItem("Save As...", new ImageIcon("src/src/if_simpline_53_2305609.png"));
    fileMenu.add(saveas);
    saveas.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    saveas.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            fd = new FileDialog(jf, "Save As..", FileDialog.SAVE);
            fd.setVisible(true);
            String katalog = fd.getDirectory();
            String plik = fd.getFile();
            path = katalog + plik;
            File f2 = new File(path);
            jf.setTitle("Prosty edytor - " + path);
            try {
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f2));
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(textArea.getText()));
                String line;

                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                    out.write(line);
                out.newLine();
                out.close();

            } catch (AccessDeniedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    JSeparator sep = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
    sep.setBackground(Color.RED);
    fileMenu.add(sep);
    // Exit
    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit", new ImageIcon("src/src/if_simpline_43_2305619.png"));
    exit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL + KeyEvent.VK_X);
    exit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    fileMenu.add(exit);
    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            // Exit the program
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    fileMenu.addSeparator();
    // Edit menu
    JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
    menuBar.add(editMenu);
    // Sub menu
    JMenu adresMenu = new JMenu("Adresy");
    editMenu.add(adresMenu);

    // Pod menu
    praca = new JMenuItem("Praca");
    praca.addActionListener(this);
    praca.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    adresMenu.add(praca);

    praca.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P, ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK + ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    adresMenu.addSeparator();
    szkola = new JMenuItem("Szkoła");
    szkola.addActionListener(this);

    szkola.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    adresMenu.add(szkola);
    szkola.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK + ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    adresMenu.addSeparator();
    dom = new JMenuItem("Dom");
    dom.addActionListener(this);
    dom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    dom.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK + ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    adresMenu.add(dom);

    // Options menu
    JMenu optionsMenu = new JMenu("Options");
    menuBar.add(optionsMenu);

    // Sub menu
    JMenu foreground = new JMenu("Foreground");
    optionsMenu.add(foreground);
    // Pod menu foreground
    c1f = new JMenuItem("Blue", new ImageIcon("src/src/blue.png"));
    foreground.add(c1f);
    c1f.addActionListener(this);
    c2f = new JMenuItem("Yellow", new ImageIcon("src/src/yellow.png"));
    foreground.add(c2f);
    c2f.addActionListener(this);
    c3f = new JMenuItem("Orange", new ImageIcon("src/src/orange.png"));
    foreground.add(c3f);
    c3f.addActionListener(this);
    c4f = new JMenuItem("Red", new ImageIcon("src/src/red.png"));
    foreground.add(c4f);
    c4f.addActionListener(this);
    c5f = new JMenuItem("White", new ImageIcon("src/src/white.png"));
    foreground.add(c5f);
    c5f.addActionListener(this);
    c6f = new JMenuItem("Black", new ImageIcon("src/src/black.png"));
    foreground.add(c6f);
    c6f.addActionListener(this);
    c7f = new JMenuItem("Green", new ImageIcon("src/src/green.png"));
    foreground.add(c7f);
    c7f.addActionListener(this);

    // Background
    JMenu background = new JMenu("Background");
    optionsMenu.add(background);
    JMenu fontsize = new JMenu("Font size");
    optionsMenu.add(fontsize);
    // Pod menu background
    c1 = new JMenuItem("Blue", new ImageIcon("src/src/blue.png"));
    background.add(c1);
    c1.addActionListener(this);
    c2 = new JMenuItem("Yellow", new ImageIcon("src/src/yellow.png"));
    background.add(c2);
    c2.addActionListener(this);
    c3 = new JMenuItem("Orange", new ImageIcon("src/src/orange.png"));
    background.add(c3);
    c3.addActionListener(this);
    c4 = new JMenuItem("Red", new ImageIcon("src/src/red.png"));
    background.add(c4);
    c4.addActionListener(this);
    c5 = new JMenuItem("White", new ImageIcon("src/src/white.png"));
    background.add(c5);
    c5.addActionListener(this);
    c6 = new JMenuItem("Black", new ImageIcon("src/src/black.png"));
    background.add(c6);
    c6.addActionListener(this);
    c7 = new JMenuItem("Green", new ImageIcon("src/src/green.png"));
    background.add(c7);
    c7.addActionListener(this);

    // Pod menu font size

    pkt8 = new JMenuItem("8 pts");
    pkt8.addActionListener(this);
    fontsize.add(pkt8);
    pkt10 = new JMenuItem("10 pts");
    fontsize.add(pkt10);
    pkt10.addActionListener(this);
    pkt12 = new JMenuItem("12 pts");
    fontsize.add(pkt12);
    pkt12.addActionListener(this);
    pkt14 = new JMenuItem("14 pts");
    fontsize.add(pkt14);
    pkt14.addActionListener(this);
    pkt16 = new JMenuItem("16 pts");
    fontsize.add(pkt16);
    pkt16.addActionListener(this);
    pkt18 = new JMenuItem("18 pts");
    fontsize.add(pkt18);
    pkt18.addActionListener(this);
    pkt20 = new JMenuItem("20 pts");
    fontsize.add(pkt20);
    pkt20.addActionListener(this);
    pkt22 = new JMenuItem("22 pts");
    fontsize.add(pkt22);
    pkt22.addActionListener(this);
    pkt24 = new JMenuItem("24 pts");
    fontsize.add(pkt24);
    pkt24.addActionListener(this);

}

String tab[] = { " adres praca", " adres szkola", " adres dom" };

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == pkt8) {
        textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 8));
    } else if (e.getSource() == pkt10) {
        textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    } else if (e.getSource() == pkt12) {
        textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    } else if (e.getSource() == pkt14) {
        textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    } else if (e.getSource() == pkt16) {
        textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    } else if (e.getSource() == pkt18) {
        textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    } else if (e.getSource() == pkt20) {
        textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    } else if (e.getSource() == pkt22) {
        textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 22));
    } else if (e.getSource() == pkt24) {
        textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    } else if (e.getSource() == c1) {
        textArea.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    } else if (e.getSource() == c2) {
        textArea.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    } else if (e.getSource() == c3) {
        textArea.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    } else if (e.getSource() == c4) {
        textArea.setBackground(Color.RED);
    } else if (e.getSource() == c5) {
        textArea.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    } else if (e.getSource() == c6) {
        textArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    } else if (e.getSource() == c7) {
        textArea.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (e.getSource() == c1f) {
        textArea.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    } else if (e.getSource() == c2f) {
        textArea.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    } else if (e.getSource() == c3f) {
        textArea.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
    } else if (e.getSource() == c4f) {
        textArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
    } else if (e.getSource() == c5f) {
        textArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    } else if (e.getSource() == c6f) {
        textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    } else if (e.getSource() == c7f) {
        textArea.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (e.getSource() == praca) {
        textArea.append(tab[0]);
    } else if (e.getSource() == szkola) {
        textArea.append(tab[1]);
    } else if (e.getSource() == dom) {
        textArea.append(tab[2]);
    }
}
}
```

Code from comment:

```
public ZmianaTla(Color color, String label, JComponent target, 
ImageIcon ico) {
        super(label);
        this.color=color;
        this.target=target;
        this.ico=ico;
        }


background.add(new JMenuItem(new ZmianaTla(Color.YELLOW, "Yellow", 
textArea),new ImageIcon("src/src/yellow.png"));
```

Comment: Sorry, but _"How to perfom methods with setFont to shorten them using whole setFont with just changing font size"_ is not parseable English text.  Please rewrite this sentence more clearly, and explain what you have already tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: Guys, this is a good question. It is just described in not perfect English. Hi tries to optimize the code (unlike many who just copy paste some tutorial without understanding what they actually do). DON'T DISCOURAGE him by downvoting, edit his text instead (I would edit, but smb. else is editing and is blocked currently).

Comment: If the code is working in its current form and would only need some refactoring, then this question is more on-topic at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to make it **essentially** shorter. I suppose your point is rather how to reduce boiler plate, repetition of similar code. The one of solutions can be following.

Implement an action to change the font:

```
public class ChangeFontAction extends AbstractAction {

    private int fontSize;

    private JTextComponent target;

    public ChangeFontAction(int fontSize, String label, JTextComponent target) {
        super(label);
        this.fontSize = fontSize;
        this.target = target;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        target.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
    }

}
```

In this action change the font:

```
target.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, fontSize))
```

Create menu items as follows:

```
fontsize.add(new JMenuItem(new ChangeFontAction(8, "8 pts", textArea)));
fontsize.add(new JMenuItem(new ChangeFontAction(10, "10 pts", textArea)));
```

You dont't need now any listener.

All in all may be not less code, but much easier to understand. And if you want to change what happens on button/menu click, you don't need repeat it many times, you will do it on a single place.

In similar fashion you can create an action class to change color.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work. It just add blank area on JMenu that doesn't change font. On console it doesn't make any error. What I noticed that this code is used  on start, for example when i made one setBackground method with blue it starts with blue background instead of white and same like font it just make blank button in jmenu.

Comment: In the constructor of ChangeFontAction in the first line pass the label to the inherited contructor like this "super(label);". I updated the code for the class, see above.

Comment: How to add ImageIcon to JMenubar. Tried just add to add.background    New imageIcon see above in first post and changing constructor ,but neither of them work.

Comment: @JakubDobrzeniecki: Look at the contructors of AbstractAction. One of the them is "public AbstractAction(String name, Icon icon)". You can extend the constructor your ChangeFontAction, pass an icon to it in addition to other parameters. In the contructor pass the icon together with label to the super constructor like "super(label, icon);".